# No large images in shares posted using LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

During last couple of weeks any shares made using [LinkedIn sharing API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) don't display large images, though we provide all required information for this, including image URL. The same happens when we use [REST Console](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin). Below you can see a sample request and how the share looks like.

```
{
  "comment": "How Triggre achieves its simplicity",
  "content": {
    "title": "Triggre / Blog / Design Philosophy - Part 3",
    "description": "In the previous two posts about our design philosophy you could read how we decided to build Triggre and why we chose simplicity as the core of our desi...",
    "submitted-url": "https://www.triggre.com/en/blog/the-triggre-design-philosophy-part-3/",
    "submitted-image-url": "https://www.triggre.com/media/1105/sagrada-familia.jpg?width=800"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }
}
```

[A share without large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd5Z2.png)

What is happening and how could we workaround it?