# LinkedIn Share API not displaying large image thumbnails anymore

Tags: image, api, share, linkedin-api

I've been using a plugin called Microblog Poster on my hosted Wordpress site to auto-publish blog entries to LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter, etc.

I have made no changes to the plugin, the plugin hasn't updated, basically everything has been the exact same. However, within the past 5 days, LinkedIn has stopped displaying the shared image as a large image, when it has been consistently sharing it as a large image before.

It will share the image, but it's now a thumbnail, showing approx 140px x 70px to the left of the shared link's title. Normally, it should show as a large, 525px x 275px image above the shared link's title.

Again, no changes have been made to the plugin, my process, or anything. Facebook and Twitter are still displaying normally. I've even done several tests with different posts to confirm it was not a fluke.

Would love any thoughts on how to fix this, or if anyone else is having this issue.

Comment: noticed this post asking the question, too. feel free to answer either one, but let's fix this! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419545/no-large-images-in-shares-posted-using-linkedin-api

Comment: Same here, and also if you share through the application, you will have your image prerendered but not text prefilled. I think, LinkedIn has bug on this.

Comment: Hi guys, did you find the reason why?? Same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [The Open Graph protocol](https://ogp.me/).  You have the option to set the size of your image, as they show in their demo.  You already know about the `og:image` property, but what about `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`?  Check it out...

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

This will show a preview of your image in a standard 400x300 format.  This should work, because LinkedIn says they read `og:` tags in determining share previews, [according to the official documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).  Although they don't mention `:width` and `:height`, I hope they would respect these tags, too, because they are part of the Open Graph Protocol.  Hope this helps!